# Retrieving values from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to retrieve data from my table and at this point just echo it to the screen. When this function is executed it does indeed get all the data as the `print_r($result)` shows me the 
data in the array. However when I just try to echo the array I get `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in .... line xxx` where xxx is the line `while ($row....`

Pretty new to php and I did a search here on this error and found quite a few hits but none of them solved my issue. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
private
function vinSearch($vin_number)
    {
    if ($this->databaseConnection())
        {

        // Gather data based on Vin #

        $this->db_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
        $query_locate_customer = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM C_Customer , C_Car WHERE C_Car.vin_number=:vin_number and C_Car.id = C_Customer.id');
        $query_locate_customer->bindValue(':vin_number', $vin_number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_locate_customer->execute();
        $result = $query_locate_customer->fetchAll() or die(mysql_error());
        print_r($result);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
            echo $row['First_Name'];
            echo $row['Last_Name'];
            echo $row['Vin_Number'];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: **You're mixing the `PDO` and (deprecated) `mysql_*` extensions!** They **do not** work together. I suggest reviewing the [PDO documentation](http://us1.php.net/pdo) for insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing different DB libraries: PDO to connect/query, and then the obsolete/deprecated `mysql_*()` functions to actually fetch data.

The DB libraries are **NOT** interchangeable like that, and connections/operations performed in one are utterly useless in any of the others.

You've started out with PDO, stick with PDO. And since you've done a `fetch_all()` call in PDO, `$result` is already going to be an array of ALL result rows. YOu don't need mysql_fetch_assoc() at all, just a foreach loop:

```
$result = $query blah blah blah;
foreach($result as $row) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: The only answer that "answers" the core issue at hand.

Comment: Thank you Marc B for the solution. I tend to learn by making mistakes and then learning from them. Still have a ways to go but I appreciate everyones help !!

Answer (score 0):

If it's already an array you should use something like this instead of the while loop

```
foreach($result as $row) {
  echo $row['First_Name'];
  echo $row['Last_Name'];
  echo $row['Vin_Number'];
}
```

Comment: Go over the OP's code, comments and [`Marc B's answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24868737/) and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below

```
print_r($result);
```

and what the error is:

```
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
```

also try to execute your SQL query in phpmyadmin.